# python print both item and corresponding list if item in a list exists in a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings and another list of lists of single strings. I can check if an item in my list exists in the list of lists but how do I print the item and the corresponding list from the list of lists?

Example

```
myList = ['one', 'two', 'four', 'seven', 'three', 'five']
LstOflst = [['do you have seven'],['if two'],['four'],['five exists'],['but three does not exist']]

for item in myList:
    if any(item in lsts[0] for lsts in LstOflst):
        print('YES', item)
```

I can print the item and know if the item is in the list of lists but how do I print the item and the list in which it is found from the list of list? I can create a dict from them using a for loop but I am looking for some type of one liner if possible.

Any help and explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following prints the item and each sublist it is found in:

```
for item in myList:
    print(item, list(filter(lambda sublst: item in sublst[0], LstOflst)))
```